# Using a hard disk without filesystem for big data

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems, bigdata

I'm working on a web crawler and have to handle big data (about 160 TB raw data in trillions of data files).

The data should be stored sequencial as one big bz2 file on the magnetic hard disk. A SSD is used to hold the meta data. THe most important operation on the hard disk is a squential read over all of the 4 TB off the disk, which should happen with full maximum speed of 150 MB/s.

I want to not waste the overhead of a file system an instead use the "/dev/file" devices directly. Does this access use the os block buffer? Are the access operations queued or synchronous in a FIFO style?

Is it better to use /dev/file or write your own user level file system?
Has anyone experience with it.

Comment: i would say the chances of getting an answer on SO diminished when you stopped writing in the middle of the qu

Comment: Thanks, i learned today to select the tags after writing the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any file system but read your disk device (e.g. `/dev/sdb`) directly, you are losing all the benefit of file system cache. I am not at all sure it is worthwhile.

Remember that you could use syscalls like [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) or [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fadvise64.2.html) or [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) to give hints to the kernel to improve performance.

Also, you might when making your file system use a larger than usual block size. And don't forget to use big blocks (e.g. of 64 to 256 Kbytes) when [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)-ing data. You could also use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to get the data from disk.

I would recommend against "coding your own file system". Existing file systems are quite tuned (and some are used on petabytes of storage). You may want to chose big blocks when making them (e.g. `-b` with [mke2fs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html)...)

BTW, choosing between filesystem and raw disk data is mostly a configuration issue (you specify a `/dev/sdb` path if you want raw disk, and `/home/somebigfile` if you want a file). You could code a webcrawler to be able to do both, then benchmark both approaches. Very likely, performance could depend upon actual system and hardware.

As a case in point, relational database engines used often raw disk partitions in the previous century (e.g. 1990s) but seems to often use big files today.

Remember that the real bottleneck is the hardware (i.e. disk): CPU time used by filesystems is often insignificant and cannot even be measured.

<sup>PS. I have not much real recent experience with these issues.</sup>

Comment: Bypassing the block cache when doing sequential reads is what i want to do, because i'm always read blocks of 1 GByte of sequential data.

But thanks for the syscall, i didn't know about them.

Comment: I would believe that reading 1GByte in one single block (and one single `read(2)` syscall) is too much. Benchmark. Perhaps using 1Mbyte blocks might be faster.